# Have different zoom between local and remote video using AgoraLab

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming

Hi I am trying to configure video streaming using [Agora](https://docs.agora.io/en/1.8.1/user_guide/API/windows_api_live.html) in iOS project and have such issue that the remove video much zoomed than the local one.

Here is the sample of code:

```
        rtcEngine = AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: AppConstants.AgoraAppKey, delegate: delegate)
        rtcEngine.setChannelProfile(.channelProfile_LiveBroadcasting)
        rtcEngine.enableVideo()
        rtcEngine.setVideoProfile(._VideoProfile_360P, swapWidthAndHeight: false)
        rtcEngine.setClientRole(viewType == isBroadcaster ? .clientRole_Broadcaster : .clientRole_Audience , withKey: nil)
```

If someone have such issue pls share how you solved this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Need set the `swapWidthAndHeight` parameter to `true` if `setChannelProfile` is Live Broadcasting.

```
func didRotateScreen() {
       if rtcEngine != nil {
            if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
                rtcEngine.setVideoProfile(._VideoProfile_360P, swapWidthAndHeight: false)
            } else {
                rtcEngine.setVideoProfile(._VideoProfile_360P, swapWidthAndHeight: true)
            }
        }
 }
```